# Readonly text input scroll effect for long text in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to mimic the way the scroll works on a text input with readonly="readonly".  The way it works is that if the text is longer than the box, you can highlight and scroll to see all of it without there being a scroll bar.

I would like to have this same effect but within a paragraph or heading inside of a div.  Is there anyway to do this, or should I just use a text input with readonly="readonly" and style it to look like my heading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, with an extra container and very little Javascript.

Add a container div around the element you want to scroll without scrollbars. And with Javascript, calculate the `scrollHeight` (height without scrollbars) of your element, and set it to your container's `height`.

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/keune/Cb4jw/1/

But as you mentioned, i think styling a readonly input to look like a heading would be a cleaner solution and work without javascript. Your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The example you provided works perfectly in firefox but not in IE.  Any ideas on how I can make it work in all browswers?

Comment: Ah, IE. I should've tested it. Looks like it even doesn't work when scrollbars are visible. I'll look into it and update my answer if i come up with something. But again, you have the option to use a readonly input which seems better in this situation.